# What exactly are you plotting for each lag value when calculating the correlations for a PACF?

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, acf-pacf

I understand this for an ACF plot.  You are plotting $x_t$ vs $x_{t-1}$ and then calculating $r$.  This gives the point $(1, r_1)$.  Repeat for lag 2: plotting $x_t$ vs $x_{t-2}$ and then calculating $r$.  This gives the point $(2, r_2)$.  Do this for as many lags as you want and plot the resulting $(\text{lag}, r_\text{lag})$ pairs.  No problem.

But what are you plotting exactly to calculate each of the r values that accompany the lags for the PACF function.  In other words, I don't know how to find the $r_\text{lag}$ in the $(\text{lag}, r_\text{lag})$ pairs for the PACF plot.  For example with lag = 2, what series are plotted on the $x$-axis and $y$-axis that are then regressed to find the point $(2, r_2)$ for the PACF.

*Edited to request a concrete example for lag = 2, since lag = 1 matches the ACF I believe?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_autocorrelation_function

Comment: I did read the wikipedia, and a number of other posts, but I'm not 100% sure I have it correct, perhaps because the intuition behind the process is missing.  Let me see if I can be more specific.  To find lag = 4, you would regress x_t against x_(t-3) to get y-hat.  Then calculate the residuals for each value of t, and then regress these against x_t - y-hat.  Calculate the value of r for this plot.  Then the point on the PACF would be x = 4, y = whatever r value comes from the final regression.  Correct?  Suppose x_t = 2,3,4,3,2,4,5,2,3.  Could you walk me through finding pac for lag=4?

Comment: I could also follow the code at 11:38 in Brandon Rohrer's video on ACF and PACF, but there is an error in the code since when he starts he uses a slice of the form [:-0], and I'm not confident that merely changing the loop to start at 1 will keep everything intact.  It runs, but I don't know if anything would be thrown off by just starting the loop at 1 instead of 0.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjaBn93YPWo